# What does this "would have been" part imply?

Tags: modal-verbs

"In the eyes of the North Koreans, he would have literally been a spy engaging in some kind of espionage activity ... I wouldn't go there (if I were him)," Kim Hyeon, 86, told Reuters. "Our members were working, fighting and engaging in espionage alongside Newman because he was an adviser."[Source](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/world/2013/12/01/north-korea-newman-bae/3795137/)

What does the "would have been" part imply here?

Answer (score 1):

It means that, to the North Koreans, it is likely that he is a spy. A spy who have been engaged in some kind of espionage activity.

To understand ***"would have been"***, you can simply understand it the same way you understand *"have been"*, but with a lower degree of possibility.

If that is still unclear, try reading *"he would have been..."* as if it was written *"it was likely for him to have been..."*.

Comment: Addendum (January 2016): Though I don't like my own answer much, reading it again right now, I don't think it's exactly wrong, because *would have been* has at least two possible interpretations: counterfactual (something that didn't really happen), and a less likely expression for "have been" (roughly speaking); and yet sometimes the two senses are sort of mixed together, like this one. -- A minor fix I did to the answer was just changing *he is likely* to *it was likely for him*